# how to prevent shape passing through another shape on a form using Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I don't know if this is too vague (this is my first time) but I'm trying to figure how to prevent the shape controlled by the user from passing through another shape on the form itself. So far I have made the moveable shape show a message when it has hit the other shape, however, I would like to change that so the user's shape cannot pass through the other stationary shape and stops moving in the direction it was traveling when it hits the object. I would appreciate some help or a possible solution, Thank you.

The code so far is here

```
procedure TfrmMazeDesign1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin

  case direction of
    1:
      ShpUser.Top := ShpUser.Top - 1;

    2:
      ShpUser.Top := ShpUser.Top + 1;

    3:
      ShpUser.Left := ShpUser.Left - 1;

    4:
      ShpUser.Left := ShpUser.Left + 1;

end;

  if ShpUser.Left + ShpUser.Width = Shape1.Left  then

     showmessage('hitbar');

  if ShpUser.Left = Shape1.Left + Shape1.Width  then

     showmessage('hitbar');

end;
```

Comment: For collision detection I believe the actual shapes are important. Circles, rectangles? Make sure to add that into your question.

Comment: Yes it's far too vague. We don't even have appropriate context to make reasonable guesses. Your sample code suggests you don't even have the collision detection figured out yet. And your question is asking about what to do when collision is detected. You don't even seem to know what you want yet. You refer to the "user's shape", but don't even give an indication how the user is controlling it. _Message boxes_ is almost certainly the worst UI imaginable where the dialog breaks the users control of the object whatever that may be.

Comment: I applaud your effort to take up a challenge you find interesting. But to be frank, it seems you're overreaching way beyond your current ability. From your code it's clear you haven't yet made a plan on how to track all the other shapes on screen that your user might collide with. Take the time to learn about _data structures_ before you revisit this challenge.

Comment: Don't use shapes, use sprites!

Answer (score 1):

When doing collision detection between two shapes/rectangles I recommend you use available method IntersectRect which allows you to easily check whether two rectangles are intersecting each other.

Next thing that you should do is that when you detect collision between two rectangles you need to move your moving rectangle back to position before collision.
In your example you are moving rectangle by one pixel which means that in case of detected collision you just move your shape by one pixel in opposite direction. That is why you could be checking for collision inside your case statement in order to have information about last movement direction available at your hand.
But if you ever intent on moving your shapes by more than one pixel you might want to move your moving shape back just so much that it is just touching the other shape

Here is a code example for this solution with some comments for better understanding:

```
procedure TForm1.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  Shift: TShiftState);
var IntersectionRect: TRect;
begin
  case Key of
    VK_Left:
    begin
      //Move shape into new position
      Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left - 1;
      //Check for intersection of the shape rectangle against other shape rectangle
      //First parameter which needs to be of variable type us used by function to return
      //the dimensions of overlaping area/rectangle of the two provided rectangles
      if IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Shape1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect) then
      begin
        showmessage('left side collision');
        //After detecting collision move shape back to previous possition
        //If you are moving your shapes by more than one pixel you might want to
        //reposition your so that it positioned just to the right of the other shape
        //Shape1.Left := Shape2.Left + Shape2.Width + 1;
        Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left + 1;
      end;
    end;
    VK_Right:
    begin
      Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left + 1;
      if IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Shape1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect) then
      begin
        showmessage('right side collision');
        Shape1.Left := Shape1.Left - 1;
      end;
    end;
    VK_Up:
    begin
      Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top - 1;
      if IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Shape1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect) then
      begin
        showmessage('tops side collision');
        Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top + 1;
      end;
    end;
    VK_Down:
    begin
      Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top + 1;
      if IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, Shape1.BoundsRect, Shape2.BoundsRect) then
      begin
        showmessage('bottom side collision');
        Shape1.Top := Shape1.Top - 1;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE MANAGED TO MAKE THIS WORK WITH A GRID**

```
procedure TfrmMazeDesign.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);

var IntersectionRect: TRect;

collision, test_collision : boolean;

up : boolean;

right : boolean;

frmMazeDesign: TfrmMazeDesign;

    counter: integer;

begin
  counter := 1;
  repeat
    collision :=  IntersectRect(IntersectionRect, ShpUser.BoundsRect, FShapes[counter].BoundsRect)  ;
    counter := counter + 1  ;
  until (collision) or (counter >= 200 );



  case direction of
    1:begin        //Up
         if collision then
            ShpUser.Top := ShpUser.Top + 1
          else
             ShpUser.Top := ShpUser.Top - 1;
      end;
    2: begin       //down
         if collision then
             ShpUser.Top  := ShpUser.Top - 1
          else
             ShpUser.Top  := ShpUser.Top + 1;
       end;

    3:  begin      //left
         if collision then
           ShpUser.Left := ShpUser.Left +1
          else
           ShpUser.Left := ShpUser.Left - 1;
       end;

    4:  begin                 //right
         if collision then
           ShpUser.Left := ShpUser.Left - 1
          else
           ShpUser.Left := ShpUser.Left + 1;
        end;


  end;
  if collision then
      direction := 0;
end;








end.
```